# Proc SQL neT operator does not evaluate properly in WHERE

Tags: sas

Can't figure out why the WHERE clause does not filter the rows selected.

The `neT` evaluation is correction during assignment, but **not** working in the `WHERE` clause (all 5 rows selected!)

```
data a;
  input a $ b $; datalines;
abcd      abdef
abcd      abcdefg
abcdef    abcd
xxyyzz    .
.         xxyyzz
run;

proc sql;
  create table b as 
  select *
  , a neT b as neT
  , a eqT b as eqT
  from a
  where a neT b
  ;
quit;
```

Table B

[image]

Comment: Is the input `A` an actual SAS dataset? Or is it a reference to a table in some external database?

Comment: Looks like the eqT operators outside of the where clause is behaving differently than inside the where clause.  Inside the where clause it appears to work the same as the `=:` operator in normal SAS code but elsewhere it appears to be ignoring the trailing spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need strip

```
where strip(a) neT strip(b)
```

This is also relevant to the topic.

```
44         data _null_;
45            a='12';
46            b='1 ';
47            x = a eq: b;
48            z = strip(a) eq: strip(b);
49            put _all_;
50            run;

a=12 b=1 x=0 z=1 _ERROR_=0 _N_=1
```

Answer (score 1):

This is confusingly documented, but *may* be correct behavior (though I have no idea why).

In the [documentation of the SQL truncating expressions](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/sqlproc/p020urejdmvi7vn1t9avbvazqapu.htm#p0imb2dwxdypycn12cqnz9bjfx1u):

> The Base SAS WHERE processor handles truncated comparisons differently than PROC SQL does. The Base SAS WHERE processor truncates comparisons based on the actual length of a string, even if a string includes blanks at the end. PROC SQL trims trailing blanks from the string values before it truncates comparisons. PROC SQL truncates string comparisons similar to other SQL processors that conform, in various degrees, to the INCITS/ISO/IEC/ANSI SQL:2011 Standards.

Now, this is confusing of course because the documentation says that `base SAS Where` would work the way you describe in the second example, i.e.:

```
data b;
  set a;
  where a ne: b;
run;
```

Per the documentation, that is expected to return 5 rows.  However, it's unclear why the SQL where behaves this way and not the way the documentation says SQL handles things - but it's also not really surprising, as I'd always understood `where` to typically work the same way in both PROC SQL and the data step.  You might want to try raising a track with tech support - or if you don't know how to do that, I can, to verify that this is intended behavior and not unintended.

Of course, *why* this is considered correct behavior (even in the data step `where`), I have no idea.  It makes the truncating expressions basically useless for comparing variables to each other, without adding the `strip` or `trim` to both ... which is the normal behavior in other modes, anyway.  I'm guessing this is some sort of backwards compatibility issue gone haywire, and I'd encourage you to create a [SASWare Ballot idea](https://communities.sas.com/t5/SASware-Ballot-Ideas/idb-p/sas_ideas) to have this behavior changed.

You can work around this either as Data _Null explains - by using `strip` on both arguments, or `trim` - or, if you actually *are* using the `neT` in a column expression as well as the `where`, you can use `calculated`:

```
proc sql;
  create table b as 
  select *
  , a neT b as _neT
  , a eqT b as _eqT
  from a
  where calculated _net eq 1
  ;
quit;
```

Comment: Indeed, it appears the WHERE clause parser is simply transcoding neT to =: and passing expression to a common WHERE evaluation subsystem that I speculate is also used by WHERE statement and WHERE= option.